# yii2 gii alhimik1986/yii2_crud_module

Tags: php, yii2

I try to install `alhimik1986/yii2_crud_module` but am getting this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'generators' in
>   D:\wamp64\www\ueb\backend\config\main-local.php on line 21 ( ! ) Fatal
>   error: Cannot use string offset as an array in D:\wamp64\www\ueb\backend\config\main-local.php on line 21

here is my config\main-local.php

```
    <?php

$config = [
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'PJYKlik7HzBS3KA95FBNwr87N9AgeQNg',
        ],
    ],
];

if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    $config['modules']['gii']['generators']['ajax_form_crud_generator'] = [
        'class' => 'alhimik1986\yii2_crud_module\generators\crud\Generator',
        'templates' => [
            'ajax_form_template' => '@vendor/alhimik1986/yii2_crud_module/generators/crud/default',
        ],
    ];
}
return $config;
```

please can someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part:

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module'
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module'
    ];
}
```